# Is this PCI-e 3.1? What type of connector is this?

Tags: pci-express, minipci

I have small USB 3.1 card connected to my ZBOX pc motherboard. What type of connector is this? Is this mini PCI-e? Can I replace this card with external GPU, connected with cable?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> What type of connector is this?

It is `PCIe M.2`.  PCIe M.2 is PCIe 3.0

> Is this mini PCI-e?

No

> The new version of Mini PCI express, M.2 replaces the mSATA standard. Computer bus interfaces provided through the M.2 connector are PCI Express 3.0 (up to four lanes), Serial ATA 3.0, and USB 3.0 (a single logical port for each of the latter two). It is up to the manufacturer of the M.2 host or device to select which interfaces are to be supported, depending on the desired level of host support and device type.

Source: [PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_3.1)

> Is this PCI-e 3.1?

No

Comment: @EugenRieck - I will just remove the statement. I looked for it on Alibaba and I wasn't able to find an m.2 cable for an external GPU case.

Comment: I already had eBay open: Article 272724818884 or 152947085130 (removed the downvote after the correction)

Comment: BTW: The reason I knew this is, that I use it (FFmpeg GPU rendering on a mini-PC similar to a NUC)

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! But what is 272724818884 and 152947085130 ?

Comment: eBay listings disregard them.